# How to use/reference Terraform output values in BigQuery Schema file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Using Terraform BigQuery Module to deploy BQ schema. Trying to define policy tags but not sure how to reference newly created Taxonomy and Policy Tag Ids inside my JSON Schema. Below is a dummy extract of how my schema.json is looking with policy tags linked to fields

**Problem:**
Schema below referencing the ids of Taxonomy and Policy Tag as

```
   ${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}
```

but when I apply TF it's not replacing values and throwing exception

```
Error 400: Invalid value for policyTags: 
projects/my_project/locations/europe- 
west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id} is not a valid value. Expected value should follow the format "projects/<projectId>/locations/<locationId>/taxonomies/<taxonomyId>/policyTags/<policyTagId>".
```

**Table_1.json** looks like following

```
 {
      "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "Email",
          "type": "STRING",
          "policyTags":{
            "names": [
              "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
              ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "Mobile",
          "type": "STRING",
          "policyTags":{
            "names": [
              "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
              ]
          }
        },
 }
```

I am outputting Taxonomy and Policy tags as following. Can Anyone please suggest how this can be referenced in schema.json file.

**outputs.tf**

```
output "my_taxonomy" {
   value = google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id
 }

output "PII" {
   value = google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id
 }
```

Edit:

I am using TF BigQuery module where my table schema exists in a separate file.

**main.tf**

```
 module "bigquery" {
 source  = "terraform-google-modules/bigquery/google"
 dataset_id                  = "my_Dataset"
 dataset_name                = "my_Dataset"
 description                 = "my_Dataset"
 project_id                  = "my_project_id"
 location                    = "europe-west2"
 default_table_expiration_ms = 3600000

 tables = [
{
table_id           = "table_!",
**schema             =  "table_1.json",**
time_partitioning  = null,

range_partitioning = null,
expiration_time = null,
clustering      = null,
labels          = {
env  = "dev"
  
       }
      }
    },
  ]

}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with you current outputs? Any errors?

Comment: No error when I do terraform plan it still shows {{my_taxonomy}}. Is it valid syntax or it should be like ${{my_taxonomy}}

Comment: Is the json in a different workspace? If so, are you using `data "terraform_remote_state"`? [https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data)

Comment: Json exist in the same workspace. I am new to TF and not sure how outputs.tf variables can be used elsewhere in same workspace also is it even possible to reference them inside json BQ schema file

Comment: Is it a Json file or are you using terraform jsonencode function?

Comment: When terraform compiles it will take all the .tf files in the root and joins them into one apply - so you can just reference it using `${ ... }`. If you are loading the json template from a file then you have to do an extra step to insert the placeholders.

Comment: once you reference the id's then terraform will know that it has to process `google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII` first and use the data at run time.

Comment: It's a json file

Comment: @Nick I have updated the post with additional code blocks included

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242250/discussion-between-nick-and-intheworldofcodingapplications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the json template using `templatefile( path ,vars )`.

Edit your json to include the vars using `${ ... }` syntax.

```
{
      "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "Email",
          "type": "STRING",
          "policyTags":{
            "names": [
              "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${my_taxonomy}/policyTags/${PII}"
              ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "Mobile",
          "type": "STRING",
          "policyTags":{
            "names": [
              "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${my_taxonomy}/policyTags/${PII}"
              ]
          }
        },
 }
```

In your terraform config edit the `schema` to use the `templatefile` function

```
 module "bigquery" {
 source  = "terraform-google-modules/bigquery/google"
 dataset_id                  = "my_Dataset"
 dataset_name                = "my_Dataset"
 description                 = "my_Dataset"
 project_id                  = "my_project_id"
 location                    = "europe-west2"
 default_table_expiration_ms = 3600000

 tables = [
{
table_id           = "table_!",
schema             =  templatefile(
                        "${path.module}/table_1.json",
                        { 
                            my_taxonomy = "${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}",
                            PII         = "${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
                        }),

time_partitioning  = null,
range_partitioning = null,
expiration_time = null,
clustering      = null,
labels          = {
env  = "dev"
  
       }
      }
    },
  ]

}
```

Comment: My Schema is in separate file and ${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id} is not working

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications, does the inline schema work when you declare `google_bigquery_table `?

Comment: Trying inline now. It was a separate schema file. Edited my original post to reflect that

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications, I've updated based on your comments

Comment: that works but a little issue. both variables giving me full path which is alright for Taxonomy but really need Identifier for PolicyTag

Comment: Seems like that a different problem to loading the json file

Comment: Yes, original issue is resolved. Thanks a lot. A slightly different issue here now is when we get PolictTag.id it gives back full path starting from Projects/Project/Location. May a Regex can be used in templatefile to extract the value after last '/'